# JavaScript increment last array element

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am in the process of trying to figure out how to increment the last element in an array using pop() and push(). I keep getting the original values after incrementing the pop array.

What needs to happen is that newArray needs to equal _array with the last element incremented by 1. For example '0,0,7' will change to '0,0,8'.

A slight shove in the right direction would be much appreciated.

```
var someArray = [0,0,7];

   var incrementLastArrayElement = function(_array) {
   var newArray = [];
   var popArray = someArray.pop();
   newArray = someArray.push(popArray++);
   }

console.log(incrementLastArrayElement(someArray));
```

Comment: You should start off by cleaning up your code--for instance, what is `_array` supposed to be? Then, you could "debug" your code, by stepping it through it line by line, and observing the variables at each point. Do you know how to do that? You should read up on how the `++` operator works. Finally, name your variables better: `popArray` sounds like an array, or a function to pop something from an array, rather than a *value* popped from an array.

Comment: It's also recommended to read the documentation, for instance for `Array#push`. What do you think it returns? More basically, what is `newArray` supposed to be doing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is **almost** correct.

You are making two mistakes :

When using the `++` and `--` operators, putting them **before** the variable performs the increment/decrement and uses the new value in the expression. Putting the operator **after** the variable uses the original value in the expression and then increments/decrements the variable.

In your call to `push` you are incrementing the `popArray` variable **after** pushing it, thus the value pushed is the original, unincremented value.

Secondly, you are creating a new array in the function thus the original one is not being altered. In JavaScript arrays are passed by reference so you can change the array parameter inside the function

```
var incrementLastArrayElement = function (_array) {
   var lastValue = _array.pop ();
   _array.push(++lastValue);
}
```

or more succinctly :

```
function incrementLastArrayElement (_array) {
   _array[_array.length - 1]++;
}
```

Comment: thank you for your input. I really appreciate it when people whom are eager to help work with the methods that I am trying to use. ab uno disce omnes

Answer (score 1):

You're not making use of `_array` and moreover, you're not returning anything. You could do the below. `_array.length - 1` gives you the last index on which you're incrementing using `++`.

Finally, you're *returning* the updated array using `return` keyword

```
var incrementLastArrayElement = function(arr) {
    arr[arr.length - 1]++; // increment
    return arr; // return it
}

console.log(incrementLastArrayElement([0,0,7])); // [0,0,8]
```

If you want to return a new array, then just add the line

```
arr = arr.slice(0)
```

at the top of the function body, so `arr` contains a new reference.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a heavily over-engineered solution for fun:

```
function incrementLast(array) {
    return array.map(
        function(elt, i, arr) { 
            return elt + (i === arr.length - 1); 
        }
    );
}
```

This maps each element in the input array to itself, unless it's the last element, in which case it adds one (true).

Or somewhat more compactly using arrow functions:

```
function incrementLast(array) {
    return array.map((elt, i) => elt + (i === array.length - 1));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var someArray = [0,0,7];

   var incrementLastArrayElement = function(_array) {
       var newArr = _array.slice();
       newArr[newArr.length - 1]++;
       return newArr;
   }

console.log(incrementLastArrayElement(someArray));
```

[JSFIDDLE.](http://jsfiddle.net/79j6ezdz/)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var incrementLastArrayElement = function(_array) {             
          _array[_array.length-1]=  _array[_array.length-1]+1;
          return _array   
       }


    console.log(incrementLastArrayElement([0,0,7]));
```

Comment: The OP seems to want a **new** array.